# Loading textures in OpenGL with C++

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL from https://learnopengl.com but I'm stuck with the texture tutorial, I had looked up many many solutions on StackOverFlow and other websites but none seem to work so I assume that this might be a new problem.

Please note that the following code is strictly to learn OpenGL and my first try at graphics programming so I kept everything in main and focused mostly on implementing OpenGL. I will try to keep the code as clear as possible and I thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad\glad.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include "stb_image.h"

//This function handles user input
void processInput(GLFWwindow* WindowInstance)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(WindowInstance, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(WindowInstance, TRUE);
    }
}

int main()
{

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* Window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (Window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create a window!" << std::endl;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(Window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "OpenGl " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GLSL " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)
            << std::endl;
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;

    float Triangle[15] =
    {
    //pos               //Textcoords
      0.5f,
      -0.5f,
      0.0f,
      1.0f,
      0.0f,
      -0.5f,
      -0.5f,
      0.0f,
      0.0f,
      0.0f,
      0.0f,
      0.5f,
      0.0f,
      0.5f,
      0.5f };

    unsigned int VAO, VBO, vertexShader, fragmentShader, shaderProgram, texture;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 15 * sizeof(float), Triangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0,
                          3,
                          GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE,
                          5 * sizeof(float),
                          (const void*) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,
                          2,
                          GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE,
                          5 * sizeof(float),
                          (const void*) (3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Textures
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    int width, height, nrChannels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned char* data =
            stbi_load("C:/Dev/Visual_Studio/C++/Git/LearnOpenGL/Wood.png",
                      &width,
                      &height,
                      &nrChannels,
                      0);

    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                     0,
                     GL_RGB,
                     width,
                     height,
                     0,
                     GL_RGB,
                     GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                     data);
        //glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        std::cout << "Successfully loaded texture" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Shaders
    const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 440 core\n"
            "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
            "layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;\n"

            "out vec2 TexCoord;\n"

            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n"
            "TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);\n"
            "}\0";

    const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 440 core\n"
            "out vec4 FragColor;\n"

            "in vec2 TexCoord;\n"

            "Uniform sampler2D myTexture;\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   FragColor = texture(myTexture, TexCoord);\n"
            "}\n\0";

    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glValidateProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Wireframe mode
    // glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    //Main Loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(Window))
    {
        processInput(Window);
        ////////////////////////////RENDER HERE////////////////////////////////////
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.7f, 1.0f);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        ////////////////////////////RENDER HERE////////////////////////////////////
        glfwSwapBuffers(Window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

//After exiting the loop, clean all resources
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

So my problem is that this code at this state only renders a black triangle
with no texture, I have successfully loaded the texture as I do get the
"Successfully loaded texture" message signifying that the if(data) block is
fine.

I have tried many many things to fix my issue including adding a 
different image with the accurate file path and a png file type and 512x512 
dimensions, Your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, it's a very good thing that you placed everything into a `main` (and provided the entire file in one piece). Obviosly don't do that when writing real world programs, but prefer this approach when asking questions here (since it allows us to easily see what's going on, and easily test the program ourselves).

Comment: Please elaborate on what "stuck" means. I don't see the question you are trying to ask. Try to spell out for us what the desired behavior is and what the expected behavior is.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm glad I left a good impression, I hope this would aid in finding the problem with my code.

Comment: Not sure if it's what causes your problem, but the last parameter for `stbi_load` in your case should be `3` instead of `0`, because your code relies on the returned data being RGB, i.e. having 3 channels. (You could also adjust the format based on what value is returned into `nrChannels`, but this requires more code.)

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Yes I left the part out, well the code I wrote exactly as it is only outputs a black triangle with no texture, I want to load the texture onto the triangle. Furthermore, my console prints out "Successfully loaded texture" which implies that the if(data) block works just fine.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just tried changing the last parameter of stbi_load from 0 to 3 but the output is still the same, a black triangle. I don't think I'm prepared to write more code since I'm barely grasping basic things like vaos and textures as of now.

Comment: Well, its been ten years since I messed with graphics stuff, but I remember you have to feed data as a buffer to your shaders, and you did, but somewhere you have to tell the shaders what the data represents. I see you passing coordinates, but you need coordinates not only for the geometry, but also the texture coordinates. While you named your array TexCoords, I am not seeing where you are telling anyone that is what they are. I see you using them as geometery. But again, I am so out of practice on graphics I barely know my head from foot.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz I have suspected the very same thing to be the issue and double checked with people but it seems what I'm doing is correct in terms of the array arrangement and buffering the data, yet I could not get any help yet on why the texture is not showing up.

Comment: Not the answer, but I suggest editing the question to add the problem description you posted as a comment. Lack of that might be the reason for that one downvote.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat will do.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz That's what `glVertexAttribPointer` are for.

Comment: @AbdelRahmanMahmoud Your code doesn't verify that shaders are compiled (and then the shader program is linked) correctly. You should add some error checks for that. At least one error is `Uniform` (should be changed to `uniform`). Next, you didn't set a value for `uniform myTexture`. After `glUseProgram`, use `glUniform1i` to set it to `0`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh my god this is so embarrassing! The whole issue was with "Uniform" having to be "uniform" and all that agony was because I didn't error check linking the shaders and compiling them, thank you very much and please post this as the answer to close out the thread ;)

Comment: I'll vote to close it as a typo instead. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Alright you do your thing man, thanks again :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to my problem is actually to error check compiling and linking the shader programs because the entire issue was writing "Uniform" while "uniform" should've been written in the fragment shader.

A simple error check would've saved so much time and energy so I hope that this answer gives insights to beginners like me.